# unicode chineese in actionscript 3/flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, unicode, cjk

So I have simplified Chinese saved in my database, characters like

```
&#25925;&#20107;&#30340;&#32972;&#26223;&#12290;
```

which is 故事的背景。

I have embed the font for simplified Chinese but the chars do not convert. Is there a function is as3 to convert unicode?

Many thanks,

R

Comment: You shouldn't normally have HTML-encoded data in your database. Unless you are storing verbatim markup, which is very rarely what you want. Ideally, you should find out where these `&#...;` character references are coming from, and fix it. Text characters should be stored as raw text (with a suitable character encoding such as UTF-8 or UTF-16LE, depending on the database).

Comment: You may try setting "Device Fonts" in the properties window, and then,

my_Txt.htmlText = "&#25925;&#20107;&#30340;&#32972;&#26223;&#12290;"

Answer (score 1):

If you use htmlText to set the textfields, Flash should do the conversion automatically. If not, you will need to convert the string to utf8 (not decimal) before sending it to Flash with something like this:
http://annevankesteren.nl/2005/05/character-references

Comment: thant for yor reply this is fine I can get the characters in now but they are a bit ragged, this is because i tunrned embed fonts off.

Comment: Also do you know which chartype I cna use? something like

Comment: I was embedding Helvetica but I take it these fonts do not have the chinese char types?

Comment: Right, you need to use a font with those characters and embed them. If you see them in the IDE then the font has the characters ;)